# My javascript drop down list doesn't work on safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I created a drop down list which works perfectly on chrome but when I'm trying on safari it doesn't work.
I don't have any clue on how to solve it!
Here my code :

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
 select#portfolio {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
}

    </style>

<form name="webpage">
<select name="portfolio" id="portfolio">
<option value="#" selected="selected">HTML</option>
<option value="agence-immobiliere-francophone-marbella/">CSS</option>
<option href="#" value="JavaScript.html">JAVASCRIPT</option>
<option href="#" value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjMpsBpg8uv6kjPOyJuTmww">youtube</option>
</select>
</form>


<script type ="text/javascript">
var urlMenu = document.getElementById('portfolio');
urlMenu.onchange = function()
{
var userOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
if (userOption.value != "nothing")
{
window.open(userOption.value, "HTML CSS javascript", "");
}

}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: add a screenshot of what's happening in safari or you can write about the same!!

Comment: Nothing is happening when I click on a element in Safari I'm not redirect to the good url.

Comment: first of all why are you using `href`s on option the only possible attributes for options are `disabled` | `label` | `selected` | `value` you can learn more about [mdn-web-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Safari would prevent `window.open()` from executing. Safari thinks that it would create annoying popups that users won't like. You can go to Safari settings and uncheck `Block pop-up windows`.

But to make it work for every one, one solution is to replace `window.open()` with `window.location.href`. This will, however, not open the link in a new tab but will replace the current tab with the destination.

There are other workarounds to this but this is one of them. If you think this works for you, here is a revised code:

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    select#portfolio {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #000000;
        background: #ffffff;
    }

</style>

<form name="webpage">
    <select name="portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <option value="#" selected="selected">HTML</option>
        <option value="agence-immobiliere-francophone-marbella/">CSS</option>
        <option href="#" value="JavaScript.html">JAVASCRIPT</option>
        <option href="#" value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjMpsBpg8uv6kjPOyJuTmww">youtube</option>
    </select>
</form>


<script type ="text/javascript">
var urlMenu = document.getElementById('portfolio');
urlMenu.onchange = function()
{
    var userOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    if (userOption.value != "nothing")
    {
        window.location.href = userOption.value;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as the correct one ! It's also improve the user experience on chrome for mobile. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No worries! As the person above suggests (I'm sorry I don't know how to tag), you could improve the readability of your HTML by removing attributes that are not related, like `href` in `option` as it won't do a thing even if you kept it and you'll be confused later on.